# Why can't I run spark-shell?

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-submit

I just downloaded hadoop, spark and hive for a MOOC. I am running Ubuntu17-10 via Virtualmachine.
I can run different hadoop commands but when I want to run "spark-shell", I get an error:

```
bin/spark-shell: line 57: home/dieter/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-    submit: No such file or directory
```

When I run spark-shell inside the bin folder, it says:

```
spark-shell: command not found
```

I updated my .bashrc file with the following:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=home/user/hadoop-2.7.3
PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
export SPARK_HOME=home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HIVE_HOME=home/user/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin
PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you've got `SPARK_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` without the leading slash?!

Comment: Yes. My hadoop commands also work without the leading slash. But I also added the slash to the .bashrc file and it changed nothing.

Comment: Can you `ls /home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin` and include the output to the question?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Sorry for my late reply. The output when I <pre> ls /home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin.hadoop2.7:
    user@Mainframe ~ $ ls /home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin

beeline             pyspark2.cmd      spark-class.cmd   spark-shell.cmd
beeline.cmd         pyspark.cmd       sparkR            spark-sql
find-spark-home     run-example       sparkR2.cmd       spark-submit
load-spark-env.cmd  run-example.cmd   sparkR.cmd        spark-submit2.cmd
load-spark-env.sh   spark-class       spark-shell       spark-submit.cmd
pyspark             spark-class2.cmd  spark-shell2.cmd

Comment: What happens when you `sh -x ./bin/spark-shell` when you're in `$SPARK_HOME`?

Comment: I get the following output:
    + cygwin = false
    + uname
    + set -o posix
    ./bin/spark-shell: 29: set: Illegal option -o posix

Comment: I am sorry but the ctrl + K option doesn't work for me...